# Count number of redundant values in 2 dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, count, overlap

I generated two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'Ex1': ['Spata1', 'D', 'E'], 'Ex2': ['Fgg', 'Wfdc2', 'F', 'G']}

dict2={'lnc3': ['Spata1', 'Fgg', 'D'], 'lnc2': ['Fgg', 'E'], 'lnc1': ['Spata1', 'Wfdc2', 'F', 'G']}
```

I want to count how many values from each key of dict1 overlap with each values of each key from dict2 and report the following elements in an output file:

1. Key value of dict1
2. Length of the values of the key in dict1
3. Key value of dict2
4. Length of the values of the key in dict2
5. Number of overlapping values between each key of dictionary 1 and dictionary 2.

For instance:

Ex1 from dict1 has 3 keys Spat1, D and E. 
The values of Ex1 overlap with 2 values in lnc3 of dict2 (Spata2 and D), 1 value of lnc2 (E) and 1 value of lnc1 (Spata1). The final output should look like this:

```
keydict1    length_value_dict1  keydict2    length_value_dict2  Number_of_overlap
Ex1 3   lnc3    3   2
Ex1 3   lnc2    2   1
Ex1 3   lnc1    4   1
Ex2 4   lnc3    3   1
Ex2 4   lnc2    2   1
Ex2 4   lnc1    4   3
```

Here is my code:

```
output = open("Output.txt", "w")
output.write('keydict1\tlength_value_dict1\tkeydict2\tlength_value_dict2\tNumber_of_overlap\n') 
for key, value in dict1.items():
    len1=len(dict1[key]) #gives length of the key
    for vals in value: #to iterate over each of the values corresponding to key
        for key2, value2 in dict2.items(): #iterates over keys and values of second dictionary
            len2=len(dict2[key2])
            counter = 0 #sets counter to 0
            for vals2 in value2:
                if vals == vals2: #checks values if equal to each other
                    counter = counter + 1 #if it is equal, it adds 1 to the counter, then it is supposed to reset it when it gets to next key2
            newline= key,str(len1),key2,str(len2),str(counter) #For some reason, i cant output the file in the command below except if the integers are converted to strings. Not sure if there is a better trick
            output.write('\t'.join(newline)+"\n")
```

The scripts works without errors. BUT, the output is not as expected. Each time it loops, it is not adding the counter more than once, and then it writes each paired comparison on a separate line.

I couldn't figure out where the error is yet. Here is the output with the above script:

```
keydict1    length_value_dict1  keydict2    length_value_dict2  Number_of_overlap
Ex2 4   lnc3    3   1
Ex2 4   lnc2    2   1
Ex2 4   lnc1    4   0
Ex2 4   lnc3    3   0
Ex2 4   lnc2    2   0
Ex2 4   lnc1    4   1
Ex2 4   lnc3    3   0
Ex2 4   lnc2    2   0
Ex2 4   lnc1    4   1
Ex2 4   lnc3    3   0
Ex2 4   lnc2    2   0
Ex2 4   lnc1    4   1
Ex1 3   lnc3    3   1
Ex1 3   lnc2    2   0
Ex1 3   lnc1    4   1
Ex1 3   lnc3    3   1
Ex1 3   lnc2    2   0
Ex1 3   lnc1    4   0
Ex1 3   lnc3    3   0
Ex1 3   lnc2    2   1
Ex1 3   lnc1    4   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is supposed to look like this.

```
for k1, v1 in dict1.items():
    for k2, v2 in dict2.items():
        # now find the number of items that appear in both v1 and v2
```

But as you now notice, your algorithm does this.

```
for k1, v1 in dict1.items():
    for v in v1:
        for k2, v2 in dict2.items():
```

Effectively, you find how many times the item `v` in `v1` appears in `v2`, which should either be 0 or 1. And because of that `for v in v1` loop, you check the redundancy of items between the keys `k1` and `k2` multiple times.

Now let's go back to the original algorithm. All we want to find is the number of elements in the [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) between the two lists, `v1` and `v2`. And since intersection is a set concept, we simply have to do `len(set(v1).intersection(v2))`. A simple snippet that can achieve all this, with no special formatting, is the following.

```
dict1 = {'Ex1': ['Spata1', 'D', 'E'], 'Ex2': ['Fgg', 'Wfdc2', 'F', 'G']}
dict2 = {'lnc3': ['Spata1', 'Fgg', 'D'], 'lnc2': ['Fgg', 'E'], 'lnc1': ['Spata1', 'Wfdc2', 'F', 'G']}

for k1, v1 in dict1.items():
    for k2, v2 in dict2.items():
        print '%3s %5d %10s %5d %5d' % (k1, len(v1), k2, len(v2), len(set(v1).intersection(v2)))
```

Note that dictionaries have no concept of key ordering in the way you'd expect them to. There are [ways](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to remedy this if you really want to.

```
Ex2     4       lnc3     3     1
Ex2     4       lnc2     2     1
Ex2     4       lnc1     4     3
Ex1     3       lnc3     3     2
Ex1     3       lnc2     2     1
Ex1     3       lnc1     4     1
```

---

If your lists have duplicate values, using a set intersection can skew your counting because sets ignore duplicate elements. The traditional way to find the overlap then it to create a dictionary on each element count in, say, `v2`, and then for each item in `v1` see how times it exists in `v2` and sum up the total. In code:

```
from collections import Counter

v2_counts = Counter(v2)
overlap = sum(v2_counts.get(v, 0) for v in v1)
```

The method `get(key, default_value)` tries to fetch the value of the dictionary with key `key` and if that doesn't exist, it will return `default_value`.

Comment: This answers it. I went over the methods to fix the dictionary ordering and i found that i can use sorted. In your script it would not make a difference though as your method works irrespective of the sorted list. Two questions: I often see "print '%3s %5d %10s %5d %5d' %" in python scripts but i dont get what are the criteria to choose 3s, 5d ... or why dont you immediately print the second part. Second, as you indicated in your comment, what if there are duplicate values for the same key. how can we account for counting twice?

Comment: @BioProgram I've updated the answer to show an approach for duplicate elements in your lists. The numbers in `'%3s %5d'` are chosen somewhat arbitrarily for eye-pleasing reasons. They simply say allocate 3 spaces for a string and then allocate another 5 spaces for an integer. If my integer has only 2 digits, it'll be followed by 3 empty spaces to keep to the 5-space allocation. The reason I prefer them over tabs is that you can't guarantee your results will be perfectly aligned. Compare printing `'1234567\t1'`, `'12345678\t1'`, `'%8d %1d' % (1234567, 1)` and `'%8d %1d' % (12345678, 1)`.

Comment: What if you cant predict the number of spaces for each of the strings or digits? the example i had above has them set and make it simple. But in reality, that can vary significantly. In that case, would you still recommend that above method?

Comment: @BioProgram It depends on the situation, I guess. I've mostly dealt with calcuations or well-structured data so generally I have a good idea the maximum range of my variables. If a value could range widly, I'd go with the highest value I'd expect it to take if I really wanted aligned data. But again, there are many ways to go about and it depends on both the situation and your preferences.

Comment: is there a private chat option with you ?